# Angular CLI command to display all existing routes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there an angular CLI command that displays all the existing routes of the app?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a regular question. Rails@4 had this feature for instance. So it's not that exotic... Peace hombré

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** - there is not an Angular CLI command as of today that will display all your existing routes.

You can take a look at the [Official Angular CLI documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) which lists all the available commands.

Answer (score 0):

Angular router supports ForRoot and ForChild. One parent Route State and Multiple Child Route State. parent Route State usually set in app.module.ts. Child Route states will be added in the lazy loaded modules.

When user access the URL, the corresponding configured component will be rendered, those routes will be added in the main router configuration.

May be you can add EnableTracing proeprty.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  ROUTES,
  {
    enableTracing: true
  }
])
```